# Connect to openconnect server from the command line?

Tags: command-line, vpn, openconnect

I tried finding a similar question and did but there's a caveat though, older questions use `--no-cert-check` option which is removed due to security reasons and I don't know the exact fingerprint for the server as it will change from time to time. I need to pass two inputs to the `openconnect` command using something like `echo -e "arg1\narg2"` but was not successful.

How can I do it? (below is the command I used):

```
echo -e "yes\nmypassword" | openconnect serveraddress --user="myuser" --passwd-on-stdin
```